# Updating devise fields via checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rails newbie here, please be gentle.

I've setup devise to give me some authentication on my application, and have added "Approved" and "Admin" columns to the user table to restrict access accordingly. These are working fine, and I can set the Approved and Admin flags directly in the database, but I'd prefer to do it within a view.
I've created a controller and an index view for the user table and have successfully pulled the information into a table, but I'm stumped on how I can reflect changes to the checkboxes back into the database. Can anyone help please?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPl0Y.png)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:Email, :Approved, :Admin)
  end
end
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
    <% if current_user.approved? %>
      <p style="text-align:left;">
        <%= button_to "Home", root_path, method: :get, form: {style: 'display:inline-block;'} %>
        <% if current_user.admin? %>
          <%= button_to "Users", assetusers_path, method: :get, form: {style: 'display:inline-block;'} %>
          <%= button_to "Locations", locations_path, method: :get, form: {style: 'display:inline-block;'} %>
          <%= button_to "Manage Dropdowns", dropdown_path, method: :get, form: {style: 'display:inline-block;'} %>
        <% end %>
        <span style="float:right;">
          Signed in as <%=current_user.email %> <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>
        </span>
      </p>  
      <h1>Asset Manager Users</h1>
      <input type="text" id="searchBox0" onkeyup="searchFunction(0)" placeholder="Search for email.." title="Type in a location" style="width:40%">
    
      <table id="assmanTable">
        <tr class="header">
          <th style="width:40%;">Email</th>
          <th style="width:30%;">Approved</th>
          <th style="width:30%;">Admin</th>
        </tr>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= user.email %></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag 'approved', user.approved, user.approved %></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag 'admin', user.admin, user.admin %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

Comment: Parameter names are case sensitive so `.permit(:Email, :Approved, :Admin)` will not work but `.permit(:email, :approved, :admin)` will. Ruby (and Rails) has pretty strict conventions but its pretty simple. *Everything* except ClassNames and CONSTANTS should be snake_case. That includes parameters, table names, attributes, etc.

Comment: Thanks max, yes, I've fallen foul of case sensitivity on multiple occasions, but not this time.
I presume I need a way to commit the change to the checkbox back to the db, it's this that I'm unsure of.

Comment: Actually, I think I found an acceptable workaround. Thanks for your help!